# Can I use LinkLabel on Visual Studios to link to a windows form?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, hyperlink, linklabel

I have been looking up on google to find out how to use linklabel to link to a Windows Form. All the tutorials that I've come across only link you to a URL or you local disk. Any help? I don't want to use buttons.

Comment: what do you mean? to `show` the `WinForm` by [LinkLabel.LinkClickedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: @spajce yes, by clicking on it I want to show a WinForm

Comment: try this, `private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var f = new Form2())
            {
                f.ShowDialog();
            }
        }`

Comment: video tutorial for linklabel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyuIAefi9JY

Comment: @spajce thanks it works. Answer the question so I can accept it

Comment: no problem, its okay, you're welcome.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `LinkLabel` as you would be using a button, by executing code in the click event. Open the form (or bring it to the front if it is alreay open) programmatically when the user clicks the label. You will not be able to set an URL to a form.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form2 == null) {
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    } else {
        form2.BringToFront();
    }
}
```