# Link Label in Windows form application C#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, label, linklabel

Hello everyone I'm making a school project and I'm making a simple application using windows form application in C#.

My question is can I link a link label with another form in my project  so when I press the link label it directs me in the another form(window),and if yes which code should I use.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use LinkLabel on Visual Studios to link to a windows form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465409/can-i-use-linklabel-on-visual-studios-to-link-to-a-windows-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.ShowDialog();
}
```